# Error in javascript recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, nodes

I have the following piece of code *(for the present case it may be considered as a function to remove the attributes from a valid html string fed as input):*

```
function parse(htmlStr)
{
console.log(htmlStr);
result+="<"+htmlStr.tagName.toLowerCase()+">";
var nodes=htmlStr.childNodes;
for(i=0;i<nodes.length;i++) {
    var node=nodes[i];
    if(node.nodeType==3) {
        var text=$.trim(node.nodeValue);
        if(text!=="") {
            result+=text;
        }
    }
    else if(node.nodeType==1) {
        result+=parse(node);
    }
}
result+="</"+htmlStr.tagName.toLowerCase()+">";
return result;
}
```

But it is not working as expected. For example, in the following case when I feed it the following html as input:

```
<div id="t2">
    Hi I am
    <b>
      Test
    </b>
</div>
```

it returns `<div>Hi I am<div>Hi I am<b>Test</b></div>`.

Also the page crashes if some large input is given to the function.

**NOTE: I know there are better implementations of removing attributes from a string using jQuery, but I need to work with the above function here & also the complete code is not for removing attributes, the above is just a shortened part of the code**

Comment: maybe due to unobtrusive nature of javascript?

Comment: What should be the expected results then?

Comment: @Vega: shouldn't it be just `<div>Hi I am<b>Test</b></div>`?

Comment: @Vega: even `console.log(htmlStr)` shows `<div id="t2">...</div>` once, so how come it gets printed twice??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something wrong with your `result` variable. It is undefined and global. In each recursion you would append the same string to itself, which also makes it crashing for huge inputs. (I can't reproduce anything, it crashes right away with a `Undefined variable` Error)

BTW: Your argument is no `htmlStr`, it is a `domNode`. And you're not parsing anything. Please don't use wrong self-documenting variable names.

Corrected version:

```
function serialize(domElement) {
    var tagname = domElement.tagName.toLowerCase();
    var result = "<"+tagname+">";
//  ^^^       ^ not a +=
    var children = domElement.childNodes;
    for (var i=0; i<children.length ;i++) {
//       ^^^ was also missing
         if (children[i].nodeType == 3) {
             result += children[i].data;
         } else if (children[i].nodeType == 1) {
             result += serialize(children[i]);
//                  ^^ add a child's result here
         }
    }
    result += "</"+tagname+">";
    return result;
}
```

I would not use trim(), that would produce `<div>Hi<b>I</b>am</div>` from `<div>Hi <b>I</b> am</div>`. You might do something like `.replace(/\s+/g, " ")`.

Comment: ohk, but any other alternative way to using a global variable?

Comment: thanks for the last suggestion, using a regexp is a good option than trim.

Answer (score 3):

This `result+=parse(node);` -> In you case you shouldn't merge the result inside recursion like that..

What happens is the return result from `<b>` recursion call appends the existing result with returned result. Where the existing result is `<div>Hi I am` and the returned result is `<div>Hi I am<b>Test` and so at the end of recursion you have `<div>Hi I am<div>Hi I am<b>Test`.

```
var result = '';
function parse(htmlStr) {        
    result += "<" + htmlStr.tagName.toLowerCase() + ">";    
    var nodes = htmlStr.childNodes;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        var node = nodes[i];        
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            var text = $.trim(node.nodeValue);
            if (text !== "") {
                result += text;
            }
        } else if (node.nodeType == 1) {            
            parse(node);
        }
    }
    console.log(result);
    result += "</" + htmlStr.tagName.toLowerCase() + ">";
    return result;
}
```

**Fixed fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/FBnYT/

Comment: if I append a `<p>check<p>` in the html, the page crashes! even the fiddle :P

Comment: @gopi1410 It is your recursion logic :P anyways.. let me check why it is failing.. most likely due to tail recursion.

Comment: yeah, I know that :P
but I had to use this only. Maybe as Vega said its due to the global variable.

Comment: @gopi1410 Nope.. not that.. but yea using local is suggested.. however adding another child node is leading to an endless recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
result+="<"+htmlStr.tagName.toLowerCase()+">";
```

to:

```
var result="<"+htmlStr.tagName.toLowerCase()+">";
```

WOrks fine in demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/qtuUA/

Comment: Check appending a `<p>check</p>` in the html

Answer (score 0):

The crash occurs because the loop control variable is not locally scoped.  So in addition to the other recommended changes:

for (**var** i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)

...